# Angular 6 view not updating to correct data on page load

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have this angular 6 application where I have implemented a login using Firebase's Google login. I have added a button that says **Login** when you are logged out, or if you are logged in, the button says **Logout** and it also shows the email address that you are currently logged in with.

Here is a code sample:

```
<p *ngIf="isLoggedIn()" class="text-white" style="margin-bottom: 0; padding-left: 10px">{{ afAuth.auth.currentUser.email }}</p>
<button *ngIf="!isLoggedIn()" class="btn btn-danger" type="button" (click)="login()">Log In</button>
<button *ngIf="isLoggedIn()" class="btn btn-danger" type="button" (click)="logout()">Log Out</button>

constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
}

isLoggedIn() {
  return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
}

login() {
  try {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
}

logout () {
  try {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => {
      this.hideAllViews();
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
}
```

Everything seems to work fine except that if you are currently logged in and you refresh the page it doesn't seem to display the correct state, meaning it shows the **Login** button instead of showing your email address and a **Logout** button since you're already logged in. As soon as you click on a tab or any other button or link the page updates back to displaying the email and a **Logout** button.

To me it seems that the HTML page is loading before it checks the **isLoggedIn()** method.

I have found a workaround to this by adding the following inside the constructor:

```
setTimeout(function () {
},
```

Please let me know what is the "Angular way" / best way of fixing this issue.

Comment: You can move `isLoggedIn()` into the `AfterViewChecked` method. It should help.

Comment: @DmitryS. I just tested that and unfortunately it didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the code of the `AngularFireAuth` service/component?

Comment: @DmitryS. I believe I already have. I basically initialize it in the constructor then I use it in isLoggedIn(), login() and logout() that's it

Comment: @DmitryS. Also, do you mean call isLoggedIn() inside ngAfterViewChecked() ?

Comment: Yes, if you call that function inside `ngAfterViewChecked()` it probable helps

Comment: What is the type of `this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;` ? is it an observable ?

Comment: @chiril.sarajiu no it returns an object

Comment: @DmitryS. didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

You can check the callback for `onAuthStateChanged()` and find out when your var `currentUser` is initialized.

```
/* Don't forget ot import the firebase */
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

<p *ngIf="isLoggedIn()" class="text-white" style="margin-bottom: 0; padding-left: 10px">{{ afAuth.auth.currentUser.email }}</p>
<button *ngIf="!isLoggedIn()" class="btn btn-danger" type="button" (click)="login()">Log In</button>
<button *ngIf="isLoggedIn()" class="btn btn-danger" type="button" (click)="logout()">Log Out</button>

constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
}

/*Use callback to check when the variable is initialized*/
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // If there is a user (a user is loggedIn), do something in that case
  } else {
    // Otherwise ...
  }
});

login() {
  try {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
}

logout () {
  try {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => {
      this.hideAllViews();
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you recommend putting the **onAuthStateChanged()** code inside the **isLoggedIn()** function?

Comment: @sbattou Yes, I'd sugest to put the `onAuthStateChanged` inside the `isLoggedIn`.

Comment: I tried it but the subsribable is crashing my app as it's always loading

Comment: What the condition part of `onAuthStateChanged` does alsways run? Actually it's wierd... The other idea is to move that into the method `ngAfterViewInit` or `ng AfterViewChecked`.

Comment: Yes that is correct it's always running which leads my app to stop responding after a few seconds. I have tried putting the isLoggedIn() in both ngAfterViewInit and ngAfterViewChecked with no luck. I really appreciate you trying to help me and let me know if you have any other ideas I can maybe try

Answer (score 1):

what you did is a good work-around, but what you should actaully use is `life cycle hook(s)` eg:   [`ngAfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit)

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.isLoggedIn();
}
```